# Sequence approximating $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $C$ and $z$ be positive numbers, and let $z_1= 0.5\left(z+\frac{C}{z}\right)$, $z_2=0.5\left(z_1+\frac{C}{z_1}\right)$, and so forth. How can I prove that the sequence $\{z_n\}$ is convergent? And how can I use this to find an approximation to $\sqrt{2}$?

I have no idea how to do this and I really need help. Is this sequence an increasing and bounded sequence? How can this be related to $\sqrt{2}$?

Answer (score 1):

To think about a limit, assume that $z_{n+1} \approx z_n \sim z$ as $n \to \infty$.  Then you have

$$z = \frac12 \left (z + \frac{C}{z} \right ) $$

What are the solution(s) here?

Comment: The solutions are z=+- root C, and now ?

Answer (score 0):

So $\;C,z>0\;$ and

$$z_1=\frac12\left(z+\frac Cz\right)\;\;,\;\;z_2=\frac12\left(z_1+\frac C{z_1}\right)\;,\;\;\ldots,\;\;z_n=\frac12\left(z_{n-1}+\frac C{z_{n-1}}\right),\ldots$$

Now, **if** the limit of the sequence exists *finitely*, say$\;\alpha\;$ , then

$$\alpha=\frac12\left(\alpha+\frac C\alpha\right)\implies\alpha^2=C\implies \alpha=\sqrt C$$

From the above it should be now clear, *after proving the limit exists*, how to approximate the number $\;\sqrt2\;$ ...

Comment: but how can I prove that the limit exists?

Comment: Show that $\;z_1\ge z\iff C\ge 1\;$ and with an inductive argument show that the sequence is monotone descending. For $\;C\le 1\;$ there's a similar ascending argument. In the first case, $\;0\;$ is a lower bound.

Comment: there is no way i can proof z1 > z and if 0 is a lower bound that mean z is convergent just for C > 1 when z is monotone descending. What about C<1?

Comment: I didn't understand what "there is no way"... About $\;C<1\;$: you need to show there's an upper bound for the sequence.